# Sample rate of standard sin function in C

Tags: c, sample-rate

I want to create a sin wave for 1000 Hz, 8000 sample rate.

When ı write below codes in C language on Dev C++ platform;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sampleRate=8000.00;
double freq=1000.00;
double sine,t,delta;
int i=0;

int main(){
    t=0.00;
    delta=2.00*M_PI*freq/sampleRate;
    for(i=0;i<sampleRate;i++)
    {   
        t=t+delta;
        sine=sin(t);
        printf("%lf\n",sine);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Then, I am seeing this values repateadly;

**{0.707107
1.000000
0.707107
0.000000
-0.707107
-1.000000
-0.707107
-0.000000}**

I think ı have to get 8000 sample for just one periode but ı am getting just 9-10 sample for one periode.I think ı am missing little point.Why have ı see this values?How can ı create  sin values at 8000 sample rate for just one periode?

Note that:

I know sin function take parameters x as angle in radians.So, ı have calculated delta for  sample rate for 360 degree;

delta=360 degree/sampleRate
where sampleRate is equal to 8000,
delta=360 degree/ 8000 = 0.045

and ı have tried this code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sampleRate=8000.00;
double freq=1000.00;
double sine,t;
int i=0;

int main(){
    t=0.00;
    for(i=0;i<sampleRate;i++)
    {   
        t=t+0.045; //there is delta value added every time on t values
        sine=sin(M_PI*t/180);
        printf("%lf\n",sine);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Now, ı am getting 8000 sample rate for one periode correctly.But now, ı can't change frequency. if ı use above code how can ı change frequency?

Comment: Look closely at the value of `delta`.

Comment: You are getting 8 samples per period, corresponding to the ratio `sampling rate / sine freq`. All is correct. In order to get more samples, you have to increase the sampling rate.

Comment: BTW: it's `#include <stdio.h>` not `#include "stdio.h"`, same for `math.h`

Comment: There's no need for such variables to be global, and it just invites headaches later if you keep them that way.

Comment: The term *sample rate* is ambiguous. Seems different to the classical *sampling rate*. The formula you use for `delta` corresponds to the sampling rate, i.e. a frequency, not a number of samples per period.

Comment: Your formula clearly states that you'll have 8 samples every `PI/4`. `sin(PI/4)` is `sqrt(2)/2` = 0.707; `sin(PI/4)` is 1; `sin(3*PI/4)` is  0.707 and so on.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah ı have missing that point.Thank you...

Comment: @Damien aaaaaaah ı am getting now. that was Just a little bit confusing in my mind for a second. Sample rate about sample in one second. Thank you man...

Comment: @KaruF BTW what is that `ı` character instead of `i` that I've seen in several posts today?

Comment: @underscore_d ı know , that was quickly demo for me...ı didn't attention about coding...

Comment: @Jabberwocky ı haven't seen this character in my post.Can you point dude?Maybe it just about your scanner (etc chrome)...

Comment: In your question you have "When __ı__ write below" (i without point), when it should be "When __i__ write below". Actually it should be even "When __I__ write below" because in English "I" is always a capital I.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Oh OK, this letter is using in alphabet of my country.I should use "i" letter .Actually that comes from rule of  never use capital "İ".Because in my country that can be(we can use capital İ)...this stuff is about being without attention.Sorry for that...

Comment: @Jabberwocky The "i" without point is used in turkey as an additional vocal to the ubiqious "i" with a point. Other languages might have it, too. Some native might explain how it sounds.